# Using checkbox with python and Glade

Tags: python, checkbox, gtk, glade

I'm new on using glade, yet I've only made small examples and I have never tried using CheckButtons, and would like to make the GUI that is in the following image:

[image]

The idea was with the ON and OFF buttons, to print a different message depending on the checkbuttons selected.
I've read what's on this site "
 " and a few more, but I dont have the minimal idea how to start.
I would like to have at least one such example:
If Checkbutton was selected print: this checkbutton was selected and check whether it is selected or not.

To run the interface I know, I did this:

```
from gi.repository import GTK

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("Port_Manager.glade")
handlers = {

}

builder.connect_signals(handlers)
window = builder.get_object("windowPort")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Can you please give me a simple example of using checkbox please ? I did the GUI in Glade manually not with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using Gtk.Builder [`connect_signals`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html#Gtk.Builder.connect_signals) method which assumes that you've declared the signal handler method names (callback methods) via glade.

Anyway, you can do it programmatically. For example, have a common callback that knows which checkbutton triggered it and do something useful (more messy unless the code is reusable) or setup individual handlers/callbacks to each checkbutton.

Let's take your example and setup handlers. The approach will be, get the first 3 checkboxes, attach a concrete callback to checkbox 1 and 2 and also attach a generic handler to checkboxes 1, 2 and 3:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_checkb1_toggled(button):
    if button.get_active():
        state = "Active"
    else:
        state = "Inactive"
    print "Checkbutton 1 toggled, state is " + state

def on_checkb2_toggled(button):
    if button.get_active():
        state = "Active"
    else:
        state = "Inactive"
    print "Checkbutton 2 toggled, state is " + state

def on_checkbutton_toggled(button, name):
    if button.get_active():
        state = "Active"
    else:
        state = "Inactive"
    print "Common handler: Checkbutton " + name + " toggled, state is " + state

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("Port_Manager.glade")
handlers = {

}

builder.connect_signals(handlers)
window = builder.get_object("windowPort")

## Added code

checkb1 = builder.get_object("checkbutton1")
checkb2 = builder.get_object("checkbutton2")
checkb3 = builder.get_object("checkbutton3")
# ...

checkb1.connect ("toggled", on_checkb1_toggled)
checkb2.connect ("toggled", on_checkb2_toggled)

checkb1.connect ("toggled", on_checkbutton_toggled, "1")
checkb2.connect ("toggled", on_checkbutton_toggled, "2")
checkb3.connect ("toggled", on_checkbutton_toggled, "3")

window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

## End added code

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Running the code, we get the console output (example):

```
$ python checkbuttons.py 
Checkbutton 1 toggled, state is Active
Common handler: Checkbutton 1 toggled, state is Active
Checkbutton 2 toggled, state is Active
Common handler: Checkbutton 2 toggled, state is Active
Common handler: Checkbutton 3 toggled, state is Active
Common handler: Checkbutton 3 toggled, state is Inactive
Common handler: Checkbutton 3 toggled, state is Active
```

As you can see, the common method (`on_checkbox_toggled`) will be triggered for checkboxes 1, 2 and 3 and we can identify them by name. Checkboxes 1 and 2 will also have a concrete and distinct handler (`on_checkb1_toggled` and `on_checkb2_toggled` respectively).

You can choose which approach suits best. I also would advise you to check [Python Gtk 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which has examples that you can try.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you men it realy helps, tell me one more thing if you can, Can I change the color of the button when its clicked?

Comment: @RicardoAlves Yes, you can change button colors but that should be done via CSS. Check this [overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html).

Comment: José Fonte Im portuguese two, :). im looking to the link you gave me, and I donw know how to connect the css, with a python script, if you could show me I will be very grateful. 
Sorry, and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RicardoAlves Bom dia :) You can try this gist for a simple example in python: https://gist.github.com/fcwu/5794494

Comment: Obrigado José Fonte, Thank you. The only problem that i'm having now is changing the color of the checkbuttons when they are pressed. If you could help it would be awsome .

Comment: @RicardoAlves Checkbuttons already show if they are active or not with the checkmark. Is there any reason to change the color? I see that you are using a raspberry pi, which Gtk version it's running? Can you open a new question regarding CSS Theming GtkCheckbutton? GL

Comment: I wanna do my checkbuttons without the drawing indicator, and as it is, I can not see very well that is pressed, and it's because I'm doing a job, and I needed the buttons to be more appealing. The version of my GLade program is 3.18.3. And yes i will open a new question. Thank you again for the reply, you are being very helpfull. Obrigaaaaaaaaaaaaaado :)

Comment: Ok, checkbuttons without the draw indicator are basically ToggleButtons but ok. It becomes easier. Até já

Comment: Ok I already did the question, it's in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343162/checkbox-with-css-in-glade-python if you wanna see.
Obrigado mais uma vez José Fonte