# Set a GTK2 checkbutton background color with respect to its state

Tags: c, gtk2

I cannot set the background color of a checkbutton with respect to its state.
By default, it appears red when checked and white when unchecked :

[image]

I tried gtk_widget_modify_base() without success :

```
GdkColor colGreen;
gdk_color_parse("#90ee90", &colGreen);
GtkWidget * myCheck = gtk_check_button_new_with_label("S1");
gtk_widget_modify_base(GTK_WIDGET(myCheck), GTK_STATE_ACTIVE, &colGreen);
```

Would be quit glad to get some hints from the community !

Cheers

Comment: It's done with CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46343162/1216776

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I'am tightened to GTK2 which does'nt provide CSS features.